# $180.00 for a Stack Overflow T-Shirt?

Tags: discussion, shop

[You've got to be kidding me:](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/new-relic-stack-overflow-t-shirt)

[image: Worlds most expensive T-Shirt]

[image: Another One]

Comment: Actual most expensive t-shirt: http://most-expensive.net/t-shirts

Comment: haha thats pretty cool. DMC!!!

Comment: `DecimalPoint.MoveLeft(1)`

Comment: haha, DecimalPoint.MoveLeft(2)

Comment: Fortunately, I hear the [rep/$ exchange rate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109851/shop-stackexchange-com-purchase-with-reputation) is really good right now

Comment: I would upvote this but I can't see the problem... maybe a freehand circle would help? ;-)

Comment: This seems highly important here: http://redd.it/lheu3

Comment: Ah ha, so this [promotional offer by New Relic](http://adzerk.s3.amazonaws.com/Advertisers/d7a21c6efbd54b82b2e1e6835166d419.gif) just became a *really* good deal.

Comment: Look, economy's kinda slow. Consider it a goodwill investment into the "Cloud".

Comment: Still cheap compared to [Amazon’s $23,698,655.93 book about flies](http://www.michaeleisen.org/blog/?p=358)!

Answer (score 55):

It's a slamming deal considering that an actual Stack Exchange employee is included and shipped directly to your house.  They will personly answer any question you have to ask - no markdown required.

Comment: Please don't let it be me.  I'd hate to have to be shipped from Hawaii.

Comment: @JasonPunyon ohhh heck no, you're the discount model - we'll wait until we have our fire sale to ship you out

Comment: Then the shirt is really cheap!

Answer (score 36):

Kudos to Tim Stone for his detective skills!

We are currently running a promotion with New Relic. This shirt is actually FREE for those who  deploy New Relic's software into their app (obviously you get a code to reduce the price to zero).

Unfortunately, there is a limitation in our store that doesn't allow us to enter promotional items at no cost, so.......we chose a price that would ensure that no one in their right mind would purchase the shirt - and judging by your reactions, the price is right.

[image: New Relic Ad 1]

Comment: Tim's always good like that! :-D

Comment: Side note:  I really like the text on the back.  Made be chuckle.

Comment: what's the link?

Comment: @BrianMcCarthy This was a promotion we ran in 2011 and is no longer active.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to run a business, you need some sort of exclusivity. I bought 5 of those bundles at $180, I'll be the only one on the block.

Comment: LOL, Korvin. Yeah, you should sell them too.

Comment: You'll make it up on volume.

Comment: @klm9971 No! I'm going to wear them all at the same time DAILY.

Comment: LOL, thats right Kevin!

Answer (score 12):

Those tax cheats.  Relic is giving them away if you try their product, so they want them high priced so they can take a big write-off. Just another big corporation sticking it to the little guy! OCCUPY STACK OVERFLOW!

Comment: This joke... is not going to age well.

Answer (score 9):

It's been updated!

> NOTE: This shirt is intended only for those participating in the New
>   Relic/Stack Overflow Fall 2011 Promotion (hence our absurd pricing of
>   it).  If you want one of these awesome shirts (for free, thanks to our
>   awesome partners at New Relic,) you can get more info here).